# Get both Graphics cards working on two screens

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have 2 nVidia GeForce GTS 450/PCIe/SSE2 graphics cards, each with a DVI, VGA and HDMI port.

Unfortunately, only one of these cards is detected by Ubuntu, so I have to have one screen on VGA and the other on DVI. I'd like both to be DVI.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 GNOME, fully updated. It never worked with 12.04 unity or 14.04 unity.

I am happy to edit in any information (but I have no idea what is needed right now).

Comment: Hi Tim!  :-) What version of the NVidia drivers are you using?  Do you have CUDA installed?  (drop by in the chat room next time) :P

Comment: The latest, 331-updates. I don't think it has ever worked - even with other drivers.

Comment: AskUbuntu general room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source, Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124756/69049)

I finally got this working, 2 Graphics Cards (nVidia GTS 450) with both screens on DVI.

Here is my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer S220HQL"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 450 GTS"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "GPU-56281125-01c7-ee85-b8b9-b3e5cf94b7c5.GPU-0.DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+180, GPU-cbc59e3f-e8c1-a347-a069-b62f6b885f7d.GPU-1.DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select +3600+0 {rotation=right}, GPU-cbc59e3f-e8c1-a347-a069-b62f6b885f7d.GPU-1.DVI-I-3: nvidia-auto-select +1680+180"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "SLI" "off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "on"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Note that it only references 1 GPU, so it doesn't need another X Screen.